# Why is the type of boost::hana::tuple_c implementation-defined?

Tags: c++, boost, tuples, boost-hana, implementation-defined-behavior

The [Boost.Hana documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1tuple.html#a85c2f16caa2a1e12eefd1b3f69fa658e) for `tuple_c` states:

> Also note that the type of the objects returned by `tuple_c` and an
>   equivalent call to `make<tuple_tag>` may differ.

followed by the following snippet:

```
BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_CHECK(
    hana::to_tuple(hana::tuple_c<int, 0, 1, 2>)
        ==
    hana::make_tuple(hana::int_c<0>, hana::int_c<1>, hana::int_c<2>)
);
```

However, the [actual implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/fwd/tuple.hpp) for `tuple_c` simply has:

```
#ifdef BOOST_HANA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED
    template <typename T, T ...v>
    constexpr implementation_defined tuple_c{};
#else
    template <typename T, T ...v>
    constexpr hana::tuple<hana::integral_constant<T, v>...> tuple_c{};
#endif
```

and, indeed, the code snippet works just fine without the `to_tuple` wrapper:

```
BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_CHECK(
    hana::tuple_c<int, 0, 1, 2>
        ==
    hana::make_tuple(hana::int_c<0>, hana::int_c<1>, hana::int_c<2>)
);
```

**Question**: why is the actual type of `tuple_c` implementation defined? Isn't the `to_tuple` wrapper superfluous?

Comment: Narrow Contracts. Is there a cost to having the to_tuple wrapper? Because barring that, it's strictly an asset to be able to change implementation detail

Comment: @sehe: I get that this buys some flexibility, but why the indirection? What other type could it possibly have? is there any optimization to be had? Eg there is also `basic_tuple` that is supposedly more lightweight, but then I'd expect a `basic_tuple_c`. Without it, why not just do the obvious thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the documentation [has this covered](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-rationales-container_representation) in a FAQ:

> **Why leave some container's representation implementation-defined?**
>
> First, it gives much more wiggle room for the implementation to
> perform compile-time and runtime optimizations by using clever
> representations for specific containers. For example, a tuple
> containing homogeneous objects of type T could be implemented as an
> array of type T instead, which is more efficient at compile-time.
> Secondly, and most importantly, it turns out that knowing the type of
> a heterogeneous container is not as useful as you would think. Indeed,
> in the context of heterogeneous programming, the type of the object
> returned by a computation is usually part of the computation too. In
> other words, there is no way to know the type of the object returned
> by an algorithm without actually performing the algorithm.

Comment: Nice answer, but your link appears to point to the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "implementation defined" does not describe an implementation. It explicitly states that an implementation choice is left undocumented on purpose, for one reason or another. Of course it is implemented *somehow*. The users should not rely on any particular implementation but use only documented APIs.

Leaving an implementation choice undocumented is a sensible default unless there's a specific reason to document it. This is true even if there's only one obvious choice *today*, because tomorrow things may change.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but why? What possible future optimization is there?

Comment: @TemplateRex It's about minimal commitment. Is there any reason to commit to any particular implementation?  If not, don't commit, even if it seems (today) that there's only one reasonable choice.

Comment: Well, for one, Hana is not the most intuitive library as it is (the docs are very clear though, just saying it's kinda mind-boggling what you can do with it), and having to write an extra wrapper just adds to the cognitive load. And `tuple_c` is a helper function to create tuples of integral constants, so the purpose pretty much seems to be to actually create a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Not speaking with authority, but I would say that wrapping the `tuple_c` with `to_tuple` is in fact superfluous. The documentation states that the result is **functionally equivalent** to `make_tuple` except that the type is not guaranteed to be the same.

One possible optimization would be returning something like this:

```
template <auto ...i>
struct tuple_c_t { };
```

To be sure I made a pull request to see if we can get the superfluous conversion removed from the example.

https://github.com/boostorg/hana/pull/394

**UPDATE**: It was confirmed by the author of Boost.Hana that the conversion is unnecessary and the example was updated to reflect that.